# Java generics: What is the compiler's issue here? ("no unique maximal instance")

Tags: java, generics, compiler-construction

I have the following methods:

```
public <T> T fromJson( Reader jsonData, Class<T> clazz ) {
    return fromJson( jsonData, (Type)clazz );
}

public <T> T fromJson( Reader jsonData, Type clazz ) {
    ...
}
```

The compiler is saying about the first method:

```
 type parameters of <T>T cannot be determined;
 no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T
 with upper bounds T,java.lang.Object

 return fromJson( jsonData, (Type)clazz );
                ^
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is the definition of the second method:

```
public <T> T fromJson( Reader jsonData, Type clazz ) {
```

There is no way for the compiler to tell what type `T` might have. You must return `Object` here because you can't use `Type<T> clazz` (`Type` doesn't support generics).

This leads to a cast `(T)` in the first method which will cause a warning. To get rid of that warning, you have two options:

1. Tell the compiler the type. Use this (odd) syntax:

   ```
   this.<T>fromJson( jsonData, (Type)clazz );
   ```

   Note that you need the `this` here because `<T>fromJson()` alone is illegal syntax.
2. Use the annotation `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Comment: This answer is not right. Although the implementation of the second method is *probably* not type-safe (we can't see the implementation here), there is nothing *technically* wrong about the declaration of the second method.

Comment: That's not what I said. My argument is `Type` has no generic parameter, so the cast shadows the `T` from `Class<T>` which the compiler ought to use, hence the error. But you're correct that you can tell the compiler the type with `this.<T>`. I've improved my answer.

Comment: The problem was a bug [#6302954](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6302954) in the JDK,  fixed on jdk 6u25.

Comment: @OmarHrynkiewicz: I've upvoted Peter's answer. I'm not sure how I could improve mine.

Answer (score 13):

I encountered the same problem and found it was a bug ([#6302954](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6302954)) in the JDK. It was fixed in jdk 6u25.

I worked around one of the instances of this problem but decided to update the JDK version on the CI box instead.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a failure of inference. The first method clearly intends to call the second method with the type argument being the same type parameter `T` that it has. But probably the compiler can't figure it out because its inference system is not good enough.

In any case, you should be able to explicitly specify the type argument and it should get rid of the error:

```
public <T> T fromJson( Reader jsonData, Class<T> clazz ) {
    return this.<T>fromJson( jsonData, (Type)clazz );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I too Had a similar issue while compiling in NetBeans.
All I had to do was change the JDK version from 16 bit to 32 bit in the Settings > Compile > Java Platform.