# Compilation error with Mule sample Connector project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, mule

I am trying to create mule sample connector project as described here :- [Create Connector Project](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Creating+a+Connector+Project)
I created this project from command line and imported in in my AnyPoint Studio

But when I am trying to build it from maven command line, I am getting an error saying that

```
     [ERROR] \20140530\hello-connector\src\test\java\org\hello\HelloConnectorTest.java:[59,24] type parameters of <T,U>T cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable T with upper bounds T,java.lang.Object
```

[image]

Screenshot is also attached. Kindly someone give me any idea.

P.S. I am using Java 1.6 and maven 3.2.1

Comment: What is in line 59 of HelloConnectorTest.java?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution for this problem, previously my method was this as below

```
    line 58 protected <T> T runFlow(String flowName) throws Exception {
    line 59 return this.runFlow(flowName, null); }
```

but later on I found out the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431334/java-generics-what-is-the-compilers-issue-here-no-unique-maximal-instance)

so my updated code for this method became

```
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected <T> T runFlow(String flowName) throws Exception {
    return (T) this.runFlow(flowName, null);
}
```

Thanks.